# Declare an extra variable leads to abnormalities while running

Tags: c++

So, i have taken some ready code from a co-worker and build my own into theirs. The code compiles without warnings. The header contains a class and some declarations. The cpp file implements the methods. If i try to declare an extra method into the header file, there's absolutely no problem. But when i try to declare an extra variable (specifically char*) and use it into the cpp file, it compiles but creates abnormailites(programm does not do what it was doing, even with one declaration). If i declare the variable into the cpp file it works fine. I'm using dev c++. Is there maybe a linker issue?

this creates problems:
.h file:

```
class foo{
   char* foo_char;
   bool a_method();

}
```

.cpp file:

```
   bool a_method(){
      //do smthing
   }
```

this is not:
.h file:

```
class foo{
   bool a_method();

}
```

.cpp file:

```
   char* foo_char;
   bool a_method(){
      //do smthing
   }
```

Comment: Unless you are declaring an inline variable you should not declare non extern variables in a header file

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Unless you are declaring an inline *or static* variable

Comment: my co-worker has pre-declared a char* variable in the same header and there's no problem by the way

Comment: Something somewhere in your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're adding a `char *` member to class `foo`.  Are you obeying the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial writeup, I thought it might be an external variable declaration, but now we have sample code to work with. Let's assume this is real code.

This is the code from the latest edit of the question:

```
foo.h
class foo {
   char* foo_char;
   bool a_method();
}

foo.cpp
bool a_method() {
  //do smthing
}
```

Okay, this is wrong. First, you need it to really be this:

```
bool foo::a_method() {
}
```

And your second example doesn't really make sense at all. You've moved your variable outside of the class definition, so it's no longer a class variable. Maybe that's what you want, but I don't think so.

And, of course, you still aren't indicating that a_method() is defined as a class method of foo when you write the code.

Try fixing this stuff and see if you do better.

Do you have a book? It seems to me you need to back up and read from the beginning. This is the very most basic parts of programming.

Comment: i just edited the question if it helps. I m not allowed to use global variables thats why it bothers me

Comment: Okay, based on the edits... I'd say you have a bit of a mess. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i've already done the foo::a_method() thing the problem is using the variable

Comment: @MindVirus   Well, you aren't offering enough code above to understand the problem, and saying "the problem is using the variable" doesn't really explain the problem, either. See the comment from R Sahu about producing a minimal, reproducible example.